# How to redirect yii2 action with keypress (keyboard input) with Enter button

Tags: redirect, yii2, keypress

i m working on a form in yii2 and I dont want to use the mouse because this form will be used in Event on Projector, so I want to get input from keyboard. there are two buttons in the form, first one is *Result* and second one is *Start Voting*, i want to hide these buttons means on projector these buttons will not be showing. for Result action I am using Enter Button and for Start Voting I am using right arrow key.

my code is

```
<script>

$(document).keydown(function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == '13') {
            return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect(array('/results/getResults'));
      }
 });
</script>
```

but it is not working when I press the enter button. how can I do that. Thanks a lot in advance friends.

Comment: you cannot mix javascript and php code in the same block. If you want to redirect, use js native functions (something like window.location.replace("<your_url>");)

Comment: hi Yerke , actually it also doesn't work when I only alert('key is pressed'); i don't know why, I think it will work when I type in text box ???

Answer (score 2):

This example should be fine I hope:
Your view file (test.php)

```
<?php
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
$this->registerJsFile('/js/test.js', ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
?>
```

Your js file (test.js)

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '13') {
        window.location.replace("/results/getResults");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is working but it is not going on exact page

```
$(document).keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == '13') {

             window.location.replace("'.Url::toRoute(['votingresults','q_id'=>$key->id]).'")

        }

});
```

it gives the output in the browser as

```
http://localhost/merck/backend/web/'.Url::toRoute(['votingresults','q_id'=%3E$key-%3Eid]).'
```

and I need

```
http://localhost/merck/backend/web/index.php?r=voting%2Fvotingresults&q_id=1
```